# Using same declared variables for multiple outputs in R Shiny?

Tags: r, shiny

so I have two text outputs and I have a variable declared in one of the outputs, I want to use the same variable in the other output however the variable I have declared in the first output can't be used in the second output so I have to re-declare the same variable in both outputs, causing messy code of the same things being declared multiple times. Here is an example of what I'm talking about, this is my server.R file...

```
output$textoutput1 <- renderText({
x <- 1 + (1 * 0.25)
paste("X is equal to ", x )
})

output$textoutput2 <- renderText({
x <- 1 + (1 * 0.25)
paste("X times 2 is ", x*2)
})
```

See how I have the declare x in both outputs? Is there a way where I can declare all my variables once in the Server file and use them in all outputs without having to re-declare them?

Answer (score 1):

Just like assigning a variable within a function, `x` will only exist within your output call.

Perhaps something along these lines:

```
x <- reactive({1 + (1 * 0.25)})

output$textoutput1 <- renderText({
paste("X is equal to ", x() )
})

output$textoutput2 <- renderText({
paste("X times 2 is ", x()*2)
})
```

or if `x` is truly static:

```
x <- 1 + (1 * 0.25)

output$textoutput1 <- renderText({
paste("X is equal to ", x )
})

output$textoutput2 <- renderText({
paste("X times 2 is ", x*2)
})
```